# Installing PostgreSQL on Windows Server 2008

Tags: postgresql, windows-server-2008, windows-server

Trying to install **PGSQL** on Windows Server 2008 SP2 (not R2) x86_32. 
Got errors like "**Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly. Failed to start the database server**" and something like that. 
And also installation doesn't fill data directory - it empty.
I tried start **PGSQL** manually via **pg_ctl**(register and start) and **initdb**, but nothing works. 
Reinstalled many times with removing postgres user via Computer Management and his folder. Again, no result.

Guys, maybe you have good manuals or experience about deploying PGSQL on Server 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got solution. 
http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/2448.page 
Just register vbscript.dll and associate VBS files with scripting engine.

Comment: Dosen't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone else running issues should read [Common installation errors](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Running_%26_Installing_PostgreSQL_On_Native_Windows#Common_installation_errors), [Troubleshooting Installation](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation) and the [Guide to reporting problems](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Guide_to_reporting_problems).

This known issue with some Windows systems is documented there, and advice on how to report issues with enough info to get an answer (including installer logs, etc) is also provided.